Name error: K is not defined (Even when K is already defined and used)
I want to create an Siamese Neural Network (SNN) to recognize faces.
This is how i import in my train.py file:
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Lambda
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from utils import create_pairs, load_images_and_labels, save_embeddings

And the file train.py run as expected.
But when I run my recognize.py file.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from utils import load_embeddings

# Load the trained model and embeddings
siamese_model = load_model('models/siamese_model.h5', compile=False)

This error shows up:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/face_recognition_system/Face Recognition System/recognize.py", line 7, in <module>
    siamese_model = load_model('models/siamese_model.h5', compile=False)
  File "/Users/mac/face_recognition_system/Face Recognition System/face_recognition/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/mac/face_recognition_system/Face Recognition System/train.py", line 31, in euclidean_distance
    sumSquared = K.sum(K.square(featsA - featsB), axis=1, keepdims=True)

**NameError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda" (type Lambda).
name 'K' is not defined**

Call arguments received by layer "lambda" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 4096), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 4096), dtype=float32)']
  • mask=None
  • training=None

*Note: Even with tensorflow already installed, I can't use tensorflow.keras.X (X is anything) because it say unable to resolve.
I'm using VS code if any matter.

Somehow I fixed this by importing Keras backend in recognize.py file and added K.clear_session() at the beginning of the file.
